# How can I deal with label with the function which

Tags: r, extract

I have an output of `ci.thresholds` and I want to select a particular threshold with respect to the specificity. In fact, I want the first threshold for the lower band with an error less than `1:10000`.

I have already tried with the `which` function. It works, but I can't find a way to return only the threshold.

```
which(ci$specificity[,1]>0.9999)[1]
#[1]> 1.0855665 
#[2]>        8
```

Now the problem is that I need a way to have just `1.0855665`.

Answer (score 0):

If we need the label, then use `names`

```
names(which(ci$specificity[,1]>0.9999)[1])
```

If the value is needed, can coerce with `as.vector` or `as.numeric`

```
as.numeric(which(ci$specificity[,1]>0.9999)[1])
```